# `getJSON()` of jQuery not calling same page's function to get JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to use `getJSON()`'s demo to show its use insetead of `$.ajax`.

I've till created the following code.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test_JSON.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test_HTML" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test HTML</title>

    <script src="Script/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Enter Name:
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnView" Text="View Label of Name" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getJsonData() {
            debugger;
            $("#btnView").val = $("#txtName").val();
            var objJson = {};
            objJson["name"] = $("#txtName").val();
            return objJson;
        }

        $("#btnView").click(function(event) {
            debugger;
            $.getJSON('/Test_JSON.aspx/getJsonData', function(result) {
                debugger;
                $('<p> APPEND TEXT </p>').appendTo('#btnView');
                $('<p> PREPEND TEXT </p>').prependTo('#btnView');
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### VB code for PageMethod

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Partial Class Test_HTML
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    <Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
        Public Shared Function getJsonData(ByVal name As String) As String

        Dim jsonString As String = String.Empty
        Dim dt_jsonData As New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt_jsonData.NewRow

        Try

            dt_jsonData.Columns.Add("name")

            dr("name") = name.ToString.Trim()
            dt_jsonData.Rows.Add(dr)

            If dt_jsonData.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt_jsonData)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            Return ""
            Exit Function
        End Try
        Return jsonString
    End Function
End Class
```

I want to get data from `getJsonData()`. But my `getJSON()` is not getting executed with URL. Is there any other way I should use this?

All I need to do is:
1> Enter text in text box
2> Click on button
3> Get `textbox`'s value through `getJSON()` method and use it somewhere else.
4> And also use `appendTo` and `prependTo` methods for demo.

Comment: After reading it three times, I dont understand what you intend to do.

Comment: Because I've even tried to call the `pagemethod` but meanwhile its containing the static data and also only one. So I was asked by someone to try this way.

And yes, that `pagemethod` was not also working! It was not being executed once. I'm editing my `pagemethod` I've tried for this. Check that out too.

Comment: I've edited it. Please give it a one more try.